# Note Test Method Issue

Tags: apex, failing-tests, contentversion, contentdocument, notes

I created an apex method that checks if the content of a Note is lower than 10 characters. I have some problems with the test method and i can't make it work.
I get an assertion failed on this test: 'System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: Expected a DmlException but it was not thrown.'

The tested method called on beforeInsert and beforeUpdate:

```
public void validateNotesLength() {
        //Retrieve the map of Content Document Id - Last Content Version
        Map<Id, ContentVersion> contentDocumentIdWithLastContentVersionMap = dataSelector.contentDocumentIdWithLastContentVersionMap;

        //Iterate through triggering Content Documents
        for (ContentDocument contentDocument : (List<ContentDocument>) currentList) {

            //Get the latest ContentVersion related to this ContentDocument
            ContentVersion latestContentVersion = contentDocumentIdWithLastContentVersionMap.get(contentDocument.Id);

            // Check if the VersionData is not null
            if (latestContentVersion.VersionData != null && latestContentVersion.FileType == EL_CST.CONTENT_DOCUMENT_FILETYPE_SNOTE) {

                // Convert the Blob to a String
                String contentString = latestContentVersion.VersionData.toString();
                // Check for the 10 characters minimum limit (contentString has already 7 characters <p></p>)
                if (contentString.stripHtmlTags().trim().length() < 10) {
                    contentDocument.addError(Label.EL_New_Note_Minimum_Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The Test method:

```
@IsTest
    private static void testValidateNotesLength() {

        // New Account for MIMO
        Account testAccount = UTL_DataFactory.createAccount(new Map<String, Object>{
                'EL_Email__c' => 'test2@email.com',
                'EL_BP_Number__c' => '165651'
        }, true);

        //Case
        Case testCase = UTL_DataFactory.createCase(testAccount.Id, null, new Map<String, Object>{
                'EL_New_Inhabitant__c' => testAccount.Id,
                'RecordTypeId' => UTL_SF.getRecordTypeByName(EL_CST.CASE_RECORDTYPE_MOVE, 'Case').Id,
                'Type' => EL_CST.CASE_TYPE_BEGINNING_OF_SUPPLY
        }, true);


        //Run the test
        Test.startTest();
        //Prepare ContentVersion with less than 10 characters data (3 characters long here)
        ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion(
                Title = 'Penguins',
                PathOnClient = 'Penguins.txt', // Change the extension to .txt
                VersionData = Blob.valueOf('<p>1</p>'), // Adding 'test' string to meet the condition
                IsMajorVersion = true
        );

        insert contentVersion;

        // Query for the new ContentDocument ID
        Id contentDocumentId = [SELECT ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :contentVersion.Id].ContentDocumentId;

        ContentDocumentLink cdl = new ContentDocumentLink(
                LinkedEntityId = testCase.Id,
                ContentDocumentId = contentDocumentId,
                ShareType = 'I'
        );

        insert cdl;

        Exception exc = null;
        try {
            contentVersion.VersionData = Blob.valueOf('a'); // 'short' is shorter than 10 characters

            update contentVersion;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            exc = e;
        }
        Test.stopTest();

        //Ensure DmlException has occurred and the error message contains the correct label
        if (exc != null) {
            System.assert(exc.getMessage().contains(Label.EL_New_Note_Minimum_Length), 'The error message does not contain the expected label.');
        } else {
            System.assert(false, 'Expected a DmlException but it was not thrown.');
        }

    }
```

Comment: what triggers the call on `validateNotesLength`?. Use [edit] to amend your post